# Text/Logo inside Navbar appears to wiggle/vibrate on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wrote code to make the logo inside my nav-bar expand-contract when I scroll, much like how the [Wall Street Journal](http://www.wsj.com) website works. However, when I scroll it now causes the logo and the other elements inside the nav-bar wiggle/vibrate.

Jquery:

```
 $(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > 50) {
        $('#logo').stop().animate({height: "50px"},100);
        $('#nav').css({height: "110px"});
    }
    else {
         $('#logo').stop().animate({height: "70px"},100);
         $('#nav').css({height: "130px"});
    }
 });
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
    height: 70px;
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
#nav{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(249,249,249,1);
    font-family: MyriadPro-RegularImport;
}
```

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle link, so that i can reproduce the problem;  your current code is not working in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using jQuery to add a class, then use CSS transitions for the animation:

```
$('#logo').addClass('scrolled');
```

CSS:

```
#logo {
  height: 70px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out; // using 'all' so that all properties are animated
}

#logo.scrolled {
  height: 50px;
}
```

CSS animations will be smoother and easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: implemented the .addClass and .removeClass but it did nothing to prevent the vibration/wiggling effect.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle? It's hard to visualize this particular problem.

Comment: Figured it out, it was just doing the wierd vibration thing in the inspection window. Your solution does seem to help smooth things out though.
Thanks!